# Disable Button when input is empty in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

so I'm new at react and I have this problem when I want to disable Button when input is empty in react it only works one time until ;(

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Form extends Component {
    render() {
        // start disable button when input is empty
        const success = () => {
            if (document.getElementById("id").value === "") {
                document.getElementById('button').disabled = true;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
            }
        }
        // End disable button when input is empty
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.props.addCourse}>
                <input onKeyUp={() => success()} id='id' value={this.props.value} type='text' onChange={this.props.updateCourse} />
                <button disabled id="button" type='submit'>Add Course</button>
            </form>


        );
    };

}


export default Form;
```

Comment: The code works fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-curran-m4r9d
But the question still needs more details. E.g. what the browser you are using. And what does it means "works one time", it's like it doesn't disable or enable button back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do it like

```
  <form onSubmit={this.props.addCourse}>
                <input onKeyUp={() => success()} id='id' value={this.props.value} type='text' onChange={this.props.updateCourse} />
                <button disabled={this.props.value === ""} id="button" type='submit'>Add Course</button>
    //added condition to button disabled property
            </form>
```

If the value of `this.props.value` is empty it would return true and hence button will be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

When using React, you don't want to access elements directly like you do with `document.getElem...`. You want to create a `state`. What you want to do is create a variable `disabled` that is `true` when the input is empty, `false` otherwise.
Then when it comes to adding the disabled property to the button: `<button disabled={disabled}...>`. So now the disabled property of the button will be the value of your disabled variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally unadvised to directly manipulate the DOM via react as react interacts with a virtual DOM to render a page.

see: https://dzone.com/articles/dom-manipulation-in-react

A better way to solve your problem is to check the value of  by checking `this.props.value` instead of

`if (document.getElementById("id").value === "")`

You should also store whether the button is disabled or not in `this.state`

Given this, within your `this.props.updateCourse` you can have a check where

```
updateCourse(event) {
// If input value is equal to '' then
// Set button state to disabled
}
```